# Designing an MVC/EF system without needing many parallel object models

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, oop, model

I'm working on the design of a reasonably large system to manage a repository of data and vend it out to users through various media. For the sake of argument, let's say that it's a big catalog of widgets and orders. One of the things that I'm finding unsatisfactory about the design is that I'm finding myself with a number of parallel, but distinct, object models in different parts of the system, and lots of code to manage and inter-translate them.

To be more concrete, we have at least the following so far:

1. The Entity Framework **domain model**. This is the source of all truth, and what's stored into the database. The `Widget` here knows everything about a widget. While it is a Code First POCO model, EF does put certain constraints on what properties you need to define for the model to work properly. (Trying to leave out the foreign key IDs just leads to suffering, IMO.)
2. The **view models** for the admin web app. Most of the display views could just use domain objects. But not every property should be directly editable, some must be editable in a different form than they're stored, and so on.
3. A set of **DTOs** for a web API used by a set of native mobile apps. The foci here are a) providing (only) the information that the apps need, and b) defining the shape of the JSON that comes out of the serialization process. The output is not always one-to-one with the domain model.
4. We're also working on a parallel web API through which our OEMs can see and manage their own widgets. The requirements are not the same as the mobile-oriented API or the internal admin site, so the set of data this API exposes for a `Widget` or our part orders won't 100% match.

It's all the same conceptual entities that are being moved around, but different parts of the system interact with them differently, or with different facets of them. Adding a new field, or changing validation logic, or things like that potentially require touching a whole bunch of different `Widget` classes in different namespaces, and adjusting the translating code. Not conceptually hard, but tedious and error-prone.

Even if we didn't have aesthetic objections to decorating the domain model with attributes related to rendering views and managing serialization, there is frequently more than one set of views for an entity, or more than one API, so there isn't a single set of instructions to encode.

As someone whose nature demands systematizing and simplifying things, frankly this all just *bugs me*. It smells bad. I can't escape the feeling that I *must* be missing something, and there must be a better/cleaner way to handle this.

**What sort of strategies and tools are available to mitigate (or automate?) this spread? Or is this sort of duplication inevitable?**

Am I fighting the frameworks in the way that this system is put together?

Answer (score 0):

I think overall, having the separate View Models and DTOs is a good idea.  Each of them really has really a separate responsibility.  The mapping between domain object and various models and DTOs can get to be a real pain so I suggest using something like AutoMapper to handle that.